# WebKitView catch user selection of input field

Tags: ios, objective-c, webkit

quick question for all of you familiar with `WebKitView`.

I am loading a webpage within my app. 
The Website is loading perfectly. 
This is the actual html

```
<html>
<head>
<script> 
function hideText() { 
   document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none"; 
} 
function showtextbox() { 
   let arg1 = event.target.getAttribute('data-bestellung-id'); window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsHandler.postMessage(arg1); 
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body>
    <input class="chargeInput" onclick="showtextbox()" type="text" value="" placeholder="Chargennummer" data-bestellung-id="41729" data-komp-id="275" > 
</body> 
</html>
```

When a user clicks into a textbox / input flied I want to catch this and prevent the keyboard from appearing. Instead I would like to do something else.

Is there anyway to get this done with `WebKitView`?

Furthermore I then want to update the input field with

`- (void)evaluateJavaScript:(NSString *)javaScriptString 
         completionHandler:(void (^)(id, NSError *error))completionHandler;`

after my operation is done.
Thank you

Comment: Show accompanying html that is minimal reproducible example in your case.

Comment: '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>        
        function hideText() {
            document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
        }
    function showtextbox()
    {
        let arg1 = event.target.getAttribute('data-bestellung-id');
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsHandler.postMessage(arg1);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <input class="chargeInput" onclick="showtextbox()" type="text" value="" placeholder="Chargennummer" data-bestellung-id="41729" data-komp-id="275" >
        
</body>
</html>

Comment: You actually meant `WKWebView` not `WebKitView`, correct?

Comment: And by "doing something else" you mean natively in objective-c?

Comment: Also what's the `ElementById("demo")` your html refers? Is it relevant?